# Excluding hours in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate the processing time
from time received to time completed, and I need to exclude the hours of
11 pm - 8 am because they're non-working hours. 
I tried playing with the `NETWORKDAYS` function but couldn't figure it out.

Categories are:

- Received
- Processing End (time completed)
- Start time (8:00am)
- End time (11:00pm)

This is what I have tried so far, but it throws error:

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(Received,Processing_End)-1) *
 (End_time-Start_ti‌​me) +
 IF(NETWORKDAYS(P‌​rocessing_End, Proces‌​sing_End), 
    MEDIAN(MOD‌​(Processing_End,1), E‌​nd_time, Start_time),‌
    ​End_time) - 
 MEDIAN(NET‌​WORKDAYS(Received,Re‌​ceived) * 
 MOD(Received‌​,1), End_time, Start_t‌​ime)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.exceltactics.com/calculate-net-work-hours-using-networkdays/

Comment: Still getting name errors. I don't want to exclude dates, just times, so can you walk me through what a formula would look like? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?  Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you had provided some sample data.

I assume that time received and time completed are never
between 11 pm and 8 am, because the shop is closed,
but it’s open seven days a week (365 days a year),
so we don’t need to worry about weekends.

One way of looking at the problem is that, if a job is completed
at the same time that it is received,
but *n* days (i.e., 24×*n* hours) later,
then a simple `B2-A2` subtraction will yield 24×*n* hours,
when you want a result of 15×*n* hours,
because the shop is open 15 hours every day. 
So I think the solution is to do the simple subtraction,
and then subtract 9 hours for each day the job is in the system.

This formula should do it:

```
=$B2-$A2 - (INT($B2)-INT($A2))*(1+TIME(8,0,0)-TIME(23,0,0))
```

where I use `INT($B2)` and `INT($A2)` to get the day portions
of the date/time values,
and the messy-looking expression `(1+TIME(8,0,0)-TIME(23,0,0))`
is 9 hours (8 am tomorrow minus 11 pm tonight).

Here’s a screenshot:

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]